# PHP создание папки от определенного uid

Tags: php, php5

Мне нужно создать папку на сервере от заданного uid.

```
        if($files['error'] > 0) {
            echo 'Ошибка загрузки файла 1: '.$errors[$files['error']];
            $return = false;
        }
        else {
            $oldumask = umask(0);
            mkdir(*папка*, 0777);
            umask($oldumask);

            if(empty($name))
                $name = $files['name'];

            $name = basename($name);

            move_uploaded_file($files['tmp_name'], $to.$name);

            $return = true;
        }
        //$to - папка на сервере
        //$files - массив $_FILES['file']
        //$name - заданное имя
```

PHP Warning: move_uploaded_file(): SAFE MODE Restriction in effect. The script whose uid is 20598 is not allowed to access *папка* owned by uid 82.

И папка создается с правами 755

Comment: опубликуйте пример вашего кода.

Comment: на каком сервере, в каком режиме работает пхп (консоль/вэб), fast-cgi или нет, и чем все это отличается от смены владельца папки

Answer (score 2):

```
$oldUmask = umask(0);
$filename = '/path/to/directory';
mkdir($filename, 0777);
chown($filename, 'username');
umask($oldUmask); // Это если нужно вернуть оригинальный umask
```

Помимо этого, следует убедиться, что у пользователя, от имени которого запущен скрипт, достаточно прав.

Следующие ссылки могут быть полезными:

- [mkdir()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mkdir.php)
- [chown()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.chown.php)
- [umask()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.umask.php)
- [Why can't PHP create a directory with 777 permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997641/why-cant-php-create-a-directory-with-777-permissions)

Comment: а вдруг windows?

Comment: @teran тогда вопрос вообще бессмысленный

Comment: с чего это вдруг?

Comment: Подробнее: скрипт создает папку на сервере, в том же скрипте move_uploaded_file, но все же выдает ошибку: PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): SAFE MODE Restriction in effect.  The script whose uid is 20598 is not allowed to access *папка* owned by uid 82. Safe mode я отключить не могу, а ftp не установлен на сервере.

Comment: chown не сработал, т.к. папка создалась с правами 755

Comment: @nikondi для этого нужно использовать параметр $mode для функции mkdir и установить umask на 0 в самом начале скрипта. Обновил свой ответ.

Comment: и $mode и umask использовал, не помогло

Comment: @nikondi значит сама папка недоступна для записи. Нужно выдать права юзеру, от имени которого работает ваш скрипт.